# code": 403, "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-cloud-api-gateway

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members
```

I'm unable to make this HTTP call.

here's my code is

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests

# Load the service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/home/key.json',
    scopes=['https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/'
]
)

# Check if the credentials have an access token or if it's expired
if not credentials.token or credentials.expired:
    try:
        # Refresh the access token using the credentials
        credentials.refresh(Request())
    except RefreshError:
        raise Exception('Failed to refresh access token')

# Get the access token from the credentials
access_token = credentials.token
print(access_token)

group_key = "test@test.ai"

# Set the API endpoint URL
url = f"https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{group_key}/members"

# Set the access token in the Authorization header
# access_token = "your_access_token_here"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}

# Make the HTTP GET request to the API endpoint with the headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the response was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Get the list of members from the response JSON
    members = response.json().get("members", [])

    # Print the list of members
    for member in members:
        print(member["email"])
else:
    # Print the error message if the response was not successful
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

I'm  getting this error
Error: 403 - {
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
]
}
}

The service account has these roles BigQuery Resource Viewer,
Folder Viewer,Organization Viewer,Viewer.

Comment: Do you have the group "test@test.ai" used in your code already created at organisation level? if not the group needs to present? FYI I got the response with the groupKey "gcp-developers@YOURDOMAIN". You can try the same by selecting Organisation from project selector and navigate to IAM and admin -> Groups.

Comment: yes the group is already created, when tried using the browser i can see the output, but when tried in python, creating access token and using it as headers to make the HTTP get call this error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated that when you try using the browser, you can see the output as expected, so try to follow the troubleshooting steps mentioned below:

1. Add the following [scopes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) in the workspace admin console for the service account:
   '`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly`',
   '`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly`'
2. Check whether the `Admin SDK` is enabled and the User has an `Admin role`.
3. Try setting up domain-wide delegation for service accounts by using this [official document](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account).

Check for typo mistakes in domain and group names.

Attaching the similar [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1884) for your reference.